# Cast member of virtual base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that this code won't work and I also know why, but is there an alternative?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(void){}
    virtual ~A(void){}
protected:
    A* parent;
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B(void){}
    virtual ~B(void){}
protected:
    void f(){ ((B*)parent)->a; }
};
```

It is not possible to cast `parent` to a `B*`, since `A` is a virtual base class. Not casting `parent` also gives an error. I hope I don't have to make all members public. Does someone have an idea how to access A::a?

**Edit**

Using friends doesn't work, since classes derived from `B` don't have access to `A::a`.

Comment: Without the cast, it probably fails because you are trying to access a protected field of A in B. You can just add a public getter and remove the cast to B*.

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

1. Make `a` public
2. Create a public setter/getter method for `a` -
3. **make B a friend of class A** (or just the function `f()`)

The 3rd option his works better than the other 2 if you want to allow only A (or a specific function) to have access to members of `A`. On the other hand with the other 2 options you can make only that member public (but it will be public to everyone)

Comment: 1+ Using a friend class works in this example, but if you derive classes from B, you have to add every class (the program I'm creating has a lot) as friend.

Comment: @JMRC you could create another class `C`, which inherits from A and is a friend of `A` and has a public getter/setter for A::a(). Then inherit from C where you want access to these members. So class B will become `class B : public virtual A, public C` This way only C needs to be friends with A and you can control which classes have access to the setter/getter (but this **can** get messy)

Answer (score 1):

Making an answer from my comment above because I tested it and it compiles fine.

Without the cast, it probably fails because you are trying to access a protected field of A in B. You can just add a public getter and remove the cast to B*

```
class A
{
public:
    A(void){}
    virtual ~A(void){}
    int getA() { return a; }
protected:
    A* parent;
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B(void){}
    virtual ~B(void){}
protected:
    void f(){ (parent)->getA(); }
};
```

Comment: 1+, I planned using this as last resource. Though it works, it gives users access to variables they shouldn't be able to change

Comment: @JMRC: You could forward declare class B and make it `friend` of class A. It will not expose variables to other classes, but private members of A will be accessible by B.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class A {
public:
    A(void){}
    virtual ~A(void){}
protected:
    A* parent;
    int a;
    int parent_a(){ return parent->a;}
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B(void){}
    virtual ~B(void){}
protected:
    void f(){ A::parent_a(); }
};
```

Note that:

- `a` doesn't get exposed to the outside world,
- the retrieved `a` is necessary the correct one, since `B` inherit virtually from `A`, so a successful dynamic cast of `parent` to `B` before getting its `a` field should return the same one as the solution offered above.

Now, *why* does this work?

Because a class is implicitely friend of itself.

Comment: 1+ Yes it indeed works. I was trying to implement it, but because of the amount of properties (like `A::a`) and pointers (like `A::parent`), the amount of function became enormous. I'll keep this in mind for when nothing more compact shows up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `dynamic_cast` is for. If you don't want to redesign your code, just replace the C-style cast with a `dynamic_cast`:

```
void f() { dynamic_cast<B*>(parent)->a; }
```

For this to work correctly, `A` must have at least one virtual function (as this one does). In addition, the cast will produce a null pointer if `parent` does not, in fact, point to an object of type `B`.

Comment: B isn't a complete type of A, so dynamic_cast will always return NULL.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. If you're telling the compiler that `parent` in fact points to an object of type `B`, then `B` had better be derived from `A`. If you've gotten yourself into a mess because `B` hasn't yet been defined, that's a completely different problem, one that you have to solve by reorganizing your code.

Comment: What I meant is that a dynamic_cast from `B` to `A` will work, but a dynamic_cast from `A` to `B` will return NULL. Upcasting will work, downcasting won't.

Comment: @JMRC - `B` is derived from `A`, so you can use `dynamic_cast` to convert an `A*` to a `B*`. Even if `A` is a virtual base. Try it. (you might have an issue if you do it **inside** `B`, but that's the code organization problem that I mentioned)

Comment: class A { public: A(){} virtual ~A(){} };
class B : public A{ public:B() {}virtual ~B(){} };
int main(void){
A* a = new A; B* b = new B;
A* ap = dynamic_cast<A*>(b);//Upcasting works.
B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);//Downcasting returns 0, since B has members A hasn't. A is not a complete type. 
return 0;}

Comment: @JMRC - it returns a null pointer because the object that `a` points to is **not** a `B`. Try `dynamic_cast<B*>(ap)`.

Comment: The whole point is to get a pointer to a class that is not `B`, but a base class of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B(void){}
    virtual ~B(void){}
protected:
    void f(){ this->a; }
};
```

you're allowed to access protected member from parent class (A mother class of B).

Comment: But he want to access the 'a' of the 'parent' variable, not the base class.

Comment: The OP wants to access `a` from a different object.

Comment: If B has no `int a` member, `this->a` from B's method return parent member a, so A::a.
If he wants to acces `a` member from another object (not B type or A type), he has to implement a public getter method in A class.
Or i didn't understand his question

Comment: In his case, he want to access the `int a` from the instance `parent`. You have an instance of class B (which is an instance of class A by inheritance) which points to another instance of class A through the `parent` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is not so much how to access the element `a`, but why you need a tree of diamond hierarchies in your design. You should at first step back and evaluate if you really need a tree of diamonds.

If you *do*, then instead of your current approach, provide `A` with a nice appropriate (public) abstract interface that can be called from `B`. When you start accessing parent protected attributes directly you tightly couple components, making it easy to break your code and making it very hard to change your design later in the application's lifespan.

Comment: I have a `UI` class which has a `container` and `content` class. A class like HTML `div`, can be inside another `div` and can contain a `div`. Using a virtual base class is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, some usable possibilities were mentioned, like using friends and creating additional functions for each variable. This could work in some scenarios, but not in my case. Adding each derived class as a friend has the problem that it makes the library less user friendly when they want to add a class. Adding functions per variable would add over hundred extra functions for some classes.

What I did as my final solution was creating a copy instead of a cast. Though it will run a little bit slower, the code will remain clean. To counter the speed problem. Accessing local variables is a lot faster than accessing global variables.

This is how it looks now:

```
class A
{
public:
    A* parent;
    virtual ~A(void){}
    virtual A & operator = (const A & x)
    {
        a = x.a;
        parent = x.parent;
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B(void){}
    virtual ~B(void){}
    using A::operator =;
    virtual B & operator = (const B & x)
    {
        A::operator = (x);
        return *this;
    }
    void f(void)
    {
        B p;
        p = *parent;
        int x = p.a;//Allowed.
    }
};
```

If you have a better solution, please feel free post it.